# DB2 (version:11.5.0.1077) Command LIST ACTIVE DATABASES is not working

Tags: db2, db2-luw

I downloaded trail version of DB2 (by following steps here:https://www.db2tutorial.com... some steps didn't come when i installed)and i opened Administrator:DB2 CLP - DB2COPY1 -db2, then i have given the cmd as

db2 => LIST ACTIVE DATABASES

output(error):

SQL1096N The command is not valid for this node type.

db2 =>

it's not working, here version of DB2 is:11.5.0.1077,Please advice how to proceed further.In fact not only this command, so many commands are not working.

Comment: Are you running db2 clp on the server (contrary to a client node)? I don't know windows, but you can try running db2licm -l and see what it says

Comment: db2 => db2licm -l
DB21034E  The command was processed as an SQL statement because it was not a
valid Command Line Processor command.  During SQL processing it returned:
SQL1024N  A database connection does not exist.  SQLSTATE=08003
db2 =>

Comment: You can not run that from within db2clp

Comment: I am not running db2 clp, I am running db2 command window administrator as mentioned in the above tutorial(https://www.db2tutorial.com/getting-started/create-db2-sample-database/)..i working on windows.means shall i run db2 clp for sql.Actually I want to practise database using db2.I don't want other things like mainframes,cobol etc.

Comment: where I need to run? pls suggest.I am running db2 command window administrator.

Comment: What other alternative do you have in the start menu under db2? I cant remember what the tool is called

Answer (score 2):

The message:

> "SQL1096N The command is not valid for this node type."

as a response to `"list active databases"` command
usually means that you did not install a Db2-server product, **or** you have multiple Db2-products installed and you chose to act on a client instance instead of a server instance.

You might have installed a full Db2-client product by accident, by clicking the wrong button on the setup program gui page for `Install a product`, **or** the installable image that you downloaded was not a server image (but instead a client image).

Different ways to see the node type:

- You can see which Db2 product(s) you installed if you run
  `appwiz.cpl` from the Windows Start menu and examine the list.
- You can also see what you installed if you examine the log file created by the setup program during installation.
- open a db2cmd.exe window (from Windows Start > Run)  and in there run the command `db2 get dbm cfg | more` and near the start you will see `Node type = ....`. If your db2cmd.exe window is addressing a server installation, then the node type will be something like `...Server edition with local and remote clients`. If you see `Node type = Client`, then you are not addressing a server installation. So in this case, you can either uninstall the client image and install a server image, or configure your db2cmd.exe window to address a server installation.

If you have multiple Db2 products installed then run the `Default DB2 and Database Client Interface Selection wizard` which should appear in your Windows Start menu under the IBM Db2 group. This lets you choose which instance to make the default, so that when you run a db2cwadmin/db2cmd window, then the correct product gets addressed.

If you installed a Db2-server product, then you can run `db2cwadmin.bat` (from the Windows Start Menu) and in that window the commands `db2start` and `db2stop` will be available, and the command-line `db2 list active databases` will report (by default) one local database called SAMPLE assuming you created the default database in the `First Steps` that runs after installation.

If you installed a Db2-server product, with **all the default settings** on a Microsoft Windows operating-system, then you will also see a process called `db2sysc.exe` in the `Task List` when the Db2-instance is running.

Verify that you downloaded the *server* image from IBM, and then re-run the setup program and ensure you choose to install a server product.

Comment: Here I am running in db2 command window administrator, and i ran the appwiz.cpl, then db2 => appwiz.cpl
DB21034E  The command was processed as an SQL statement because it was not a
valid Command Line Processor command.  During SQL processing it returned:
SQL1024N  A database connection does not exist.  SQLSTATE=08003.

Comment: then I ran db2 get dbm cfg | more, then db2 => get dbm cfg | more
SQL0104N  An unexpected token "|" was found following "CFG".  Expected tokens
may include:  "END-OF-STATEMENT".  SQLSTATE=42601,

Comment: then i ran db2cwadmin.bat,db2 => db2cwadmin.bat
DB21034E  The command was processed as an SQL statement because it was not a
valid Command Line Processor command.  During SQL processing it returned:
SQL1024N  A database connection does not exist.  SQLSTATE=08003
db2 =>

Comment: Understand the difference between the __interactive__ command line processor(db2.exe), and the db2cmd.exe __shell__. Click Start > Run > db2cwadmin.bat , or Start > Run > db2cmd.exe ,and in the new window that opens, there run the commands that I show in the answer.  You cannot run operating-system commands in the interactive clp, instead you run them in db2cmd.exe.